# Android AutoCompleteTextView, how to choose what it displays in the drop down?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to somehow change AutoCompleteTextView to blindly suggest everything it has in it's ArrayAdapter (I'm using an online source for text completion suggestions so it will never be a very big array).  Is there a way to do it (make a custom array, or filter...or something), or should I just somehow roll my own custom edit view that just displays whatever I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to somehow change AutoCompleteTextView to blindly suggest
>   everything it has in it's ArrayAdapter

I guess you want to just use the `AutoCompleteTextview`'s look and behavior without actually filtering the items. Now I'm not sure if I remember correctly the auto complete process but I think you could just extend `AutoCompleteTextView` and override the [`performFiltering()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#performFiltering%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) method to do nothing(in there the widget calls the `filter()` method on the adapter to limit the items in it). Then use that custom widget in your app instead of the default one.

If that doesn't work, make a custom adapter and create your own `Filter`(which you'll be returning in the `getFilter()` method of the adapter) which simply ignores the filtering.

But I find what you're trying to do a bit strange.